# Trying to check if key present in array of objects inside of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, key-value

I need a way to return true or false if in changeFields array "printLogs" key is present or not. The object is shown below. I have tried looping but somehow cant get my head to wrap around it.

```
const printObj = [
  {
    _id: "656a69e14",
    document: { _id: "65b891" },
    user: "654cfbba3ea455b55b057195",
    changeFields: [
      {
        change: "update",
        quantity: [
          2,
          3,
          "2023 1 Oz Silver Maple Leaf Coin - Royal Canadian Mint",
        ],
      },
      { change: "update", subTotal: ["77.88", "116.82"] },
      { change: "update", totalAmount: ["107.88", "146.82"] },
    ],
    createdAt: "2023-12-01T19:10:54.575Z",
    updatedAt: "2023-12-01T19:10:54.575Z",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "65e0e",
    document: { _id: "651" },
    user: "",
    changeFields: [{ printLogs: "An order has been printed" }],
    createdAt: "",
    updatedAt: "",
    __v: 0,
  },
{},

]
```

I have tried javascript in built functions. The below worked to some degree but I need to return true or false if printLogs is present in changeFields.

```
const value = printObj.filter(function (x) {
  x.changeFields.filter(function (o) {
    console.log(o, o.hasOwnProperty("printLogs"));
  });
});
```

Comment: I want to know that `changeFields` array has only one `JSON` object?, In other word, It's length is always 1?

Comment: Yes its length is always 1

Comment: But in your data, first object of `printObj`'s `changeFields` has so 3 objects.Anyway, I'll add answer immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to loop thru the array using `array.some` to check if the key exists.  Here is an example:

```js
const printObj = [
  {
    _id: "656a69e14",
    document: { _id: "65b891" },
    user: "654cfbba3ea455b55b057195",
    changeFields: [
      {
        change: "update",
        quantity: [
          2,
          3,
          "2023 1 Oz Silver Maple Leaf Coin - Royal Canadian Mint",
        ],
      },
      { change: "update", subTotal: ["77.88", "116.82"] },
      { change: "update", totalAmount: ["107.88", "146.82"] },
    ],
    createdAt: "2023-12-01T19:10:54.575Z",
    updatedAt: "2023-12-01T19:10:54.575Z",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "65e0e",
    document: { _id: "651" },
    user: "",
    changeFields: [{ printLogs: "An order has been printed" }],
    createdAt: "",
    updatedAt: "",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {},
];

const result = printObj.some((o) => o.changeFields?.some((f) => f.printLogs) ?? false)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array::some()` and `in` operator:

```js
const printObj = [
  {
    _id: "656a69e14",
    document: { _id: "65b891" },
    user: "654cfbba3ea455b55b057195",
    changeFields: [
      {
        change: "update",
        quantity: [
          2,
          3,
          "2023 1 Oz Silver Maple Leaf Coin - Royal Canadian Mint",
        ],
      },
      { change: "update", subTotal: ["77.88", "116.82"] },
      { change: "update", totalAmount: ["107.88", "146.82"] },
    ],
    createdAt: "2023-12-01T19:10:54.575Z",
    updatedAt: "2023-12-01T19:10:54.575Z",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "65e0e",
    document: { _id: "651" },
    user: "",
    changeFields: [{ printLogs: "An order has been printed" }],
    createdAt: "",
    updatedAt: "",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {},
];

const result = printObj.some(item => item.changeFields.some(item => 'printLogs' in item));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I add code below.

```js
const printObj = [
  {
    _id: "656a69e14",
    document: { _id: "65b891" },
    user: "654cfbba3ea455b55b057195",
    changeFields: [
      {
        change: "update",
        quantity: [
          2,
          3,
          "2023 1 Oz Silver Maple Leaf Coin - Royal Canadian Mint",
        ],
      },
      { change: "update", subTotal: ["77.88", "116.82"] },
      { change: "update", totalAmount: ["107.88", "146.82"] },
    ],
    createdAt: "2023-12-01T19:10:54.575Z",
    updatedAt: "2023-12-01T19:10:54.575Z",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "65e0e",
    document: { _id: "651" },
    user: "",
    changeFields: [{ printLogs: "An order has been printed" }],
    createdAt: "",
    updatedAt: "",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {},
];

const result = printObj.map(
  (obj) =>
    !!obj.changeFields?.filter(
      (item) => Object.keys(item).indexOf("printLogs") !== -1
    ).length
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Adrid. With this result I got an array of true false values. I need if printlogs is present even once return true. I did results.include(true) as workaround

Comment: I don't know what you want.

Comment: The reply from Timur worked for me